# Mudar a Label na view em Projeto Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, label

Criei um classe no Model chamada Pagamento.cs, onde tem os atributos exatamente escrito como o nome dos campos da minha tabela de pagamentos no BD. Criei uma view para que fosse cadastradas as informações de pagamento, porem alem de criar a view e vincular a uma model para que gerasse os campos automaticamente,  gostaria de editar a exibição da label pois o nome do campo que ele pega da model nao fica legal, e se uso uma `<label> </label>` nao pega a formatação legal. Como faço isso?

Segue código abaixo:

```
@model SistemaPagamento.Models.Pagamento

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Pagamento</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdPagamento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdPagamento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdPagamento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USUARIO_IdUsuario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.USUARIO_IdUsuario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USUARIO_IdUsuario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FORNECEDOR_IdFornecedor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FORNECEDOR_IdFornecedor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FORNECEDOR_IdFornecedor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DtEmissao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DtEmissao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DtEmissao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DtVencimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DtVencimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DtVencimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Boleto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Boleto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Boleto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Valor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Valor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Valor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DtEntrega, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DtEntrega, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DtEntrega, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se deseja alterar o nome de seu formulário, voce pode utilizar DataAnnotations em suas entidades.

Para realizar está configuracao, basta inserir em sua classe de pagamento a anotacao **Display**, segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
public class Pagamento
{
    [Display(Name = "Código:")]
    public string IdPagamento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Usuário:")]
    public string USUARIO_IdUsuario { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fornecedor:")]
    public string FORNECEDOR_IdFornecedor{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Emissao:")]
    public DateTime DtEmissao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data Vencimento:")]
    public DateTime DtVencimento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nota Fiscal:")]
    public string NF{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Boleto:")]
    public string Boleto{ get; set; }
}
```

Segue um exemplo funcionando no .NET Fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/0IqBpJ

Comment: Junior obrigado cara deu certo!